# parse mutiple js variables to php using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to save multiple variables to database, but most of the variable are calculated using java-script/jquery. so i have used .js/ajax and .php to do so but i am getting error on doing this. here is my code example-

JS/Jquery-

```
$(function(){
  $("#btn").on('click', function() {
    var name =  $("#myname").val();
    var yoursex = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
    var date = new Date($('#dob').val());
    var c_age = calc_age();
    var social_age = calcSocialAge();

$.post("insert_data.php", {
    name: name,
    sex: yoursex,
    dob: date,
    crono_age: c_age,
    social_age: social_age
},
      function(data, status){
          alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      });
});
});
```

insert_data.php

```
<? php  
include_once('connect-mysql.php') ;

      $name = $_post['name'];
      $sex = $_post['sex'];
      $dob = $_post['dob'];
      $c_age = $_post['crono_age'];
      $s_age = $_post['social_age'];



     $sql = " INSERT INTO `patient_info` (`pt_id`, `pt_name`, `pt_gender`, `Pt_dob`, `pt_C_age`, `pt_s_age`)
    VALUES ('', $name,$sex, $dob, $c_age, $c_age, $s_age );";

     ?>
```

when i am applying this code but getting the error like below -

Data: Connected successfully
**Notice**:  Undefined variable: _post in **E:\xampp\htdocs\insert_data.php** on line **4 to 8**

Status: success
I am quite new to AJAX and PHP please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: `$_POST['name']` ....

Comment: POST is a super global array defined as $_POST

Answer (score 1):

`$_post` is not [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) Change all to `$_POST`, and also check value

```
  $name = isset($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:'';
  $sex = isset($_POST['sex'])?$_POST['sex']:'';
  $dob = isset($_POST['dob'])?$_POST['dob']:'';
  $c_age = isset($_POST['crono_age'])?$_POST['crono_age']:'';
  $s_age = isset($_POST['social_age'])?$_POST['social_age']:'';
```

And `date` is object not any string value as you are expecting like `Y-m-d` or `d-m-Y`, it is something like `Date 2017-12-23T07:18:08.909Z` here

```
var date = new Date($('#dob').val());//be sure about date value
```

You are not using `quotes` to insert string type value in your query, But I suggest to insert use mysqli or pdo. Here are some link to learn about mysqli:

[**mysqli_prepare**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[**mysqli_stmt_bind_param**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

[**Prepared Statements in MySQLi**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as using `$_POST['name']` instead of `$_post['name']` ? Those superglobals are case-sensitive.

Also, you should do some kind of error checking, or checking to see if one or more fields were left blank. `isset($_POST['name'])` and `empty($_POST)` will help you with that.

Comment: I also said the same thing dear Babcock