# Fail input to database mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I Want to ask about input data to database.

```
  <?php
  include "koneksi.php";
  if(isset($_POST['daftar'])){
    $daftar = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tb_daftar VALUES
    ('".$_POST['id']."',
      '".$_POST['nama']."',
      '".$_POST['asal_sekolah']."',
      '".$_POST['jenis_kelamin']."',
      '".$_POST['nama_ayah']."',
      '".$_POST['nama_ibu']."',
      '".$_POST['alamat']."',
      '".$_POST['no_hp']."',
      '')");
      if($daftar){
        $pesan1 = "Berhasil daftar";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$pesan1');</script>";
      }else{
        $pesan2 = "Gagal daftar";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$pesan2');</script>";
      }
  }
 ?>
```

That result always show " Gagal daftar "..
How to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: remove last comma `'".$_POST['no_hp']."',` <---

Comment: @SimoneNigro No he can't. Please check again, its '".$_POST['no_hp']."',
      ' ')

Comment: @AmitGupta He's correct. It would be much easier to see if the OP used a prepared statement.

Comment: ok, right... use mysqli_error($con) for check the error

Comment: Check error? Hmm... no error. I've change to mysqli_error($conn); then just refreshed the index.php reset the text box

Comment: One thing I always do is to list the columns I'm inserting into, this helps in debugging and checking that I'm inserting the right value into the right column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra comma after the last value. You should also use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

```
if ($dafter = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO tb_dafter VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($dafter, "ssssssss", $_POST['id'], $_POST['nama'], $_POST['asal_sekolah'], $_POST['jenis_kelamin'], $_POST['nama_ayah'], $_POST['nama_ibu'], $_POST['alamat'], $_POST['no_hp']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($dafter);
    $pesan1 = "Berhasil daftar";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$pesan1');</script>";
} else {
    $pesan2 = htmlentities(mysqli_error($conn));
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$pesan2');</script>";
}
```

Comment: What is "sssssss" ?

Comment: The list of parameter types. `s` = string, `i` = integer. Did you try reading the documentation?

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not in good condition,  You need to think in many aspect like,

1. Integer value like `id` will not be in quotes.
2. Sequence matter if you not provided column names with table name, **Highly risky** without column name.
3. You query is easy to Inject, [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)
4. You have not check $_POST variable value, with `isset`, [Check my other answer about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47950592/8927508)

To cover your risk use mysqli or pdo

But I suggest to insert use mysqli or pdo. Here are some link to learn about mysqli:

[**mysqli_prepare**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[**mysqli_stmt_bind_param**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

[**Prepared Statements in MySQLi**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Comment: Consider moving to codereview.stackexchange.com where this kind of answers are welcome. On Stack Overflow, however, a general musing on the code posted is off topic

Answer (score -2):

View errors from mysql query using mysqli_error

```
else{
    $pesan2 = mysqli_error($conn);
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error: '+$pesan2);</script>";
  }
```

Comment: It is a solution since he needs to find out what is the cause of the data not being inserted to database

Comment: A debugging step answers how to fix a problem even if it is only a first step

Comment: Nothing error showing, the page just refreshed here my form code : https://pastebin.com/jNsnmVFq

Comment: @RafiPriatnaKasbiantoro is the original code with `if(isset($_POST['daftar'])){` on the same page

Comment: @JoshKisb Yes, i just have 2 files it's koneksi.php and index.php.

Comment: oh first try changing `Daftar` to `daftar` in submit input alue

Comment: Well, nothing happen...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161856/discussion-between-joshkisb-and-rafi-priatna-kasbiantoro).

Comment: It's a good answer, but this particular way to report errors is flawed anyway.

Answer (score -3):

```
 $daftar = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tb_daftar((database columns)) 
  VALUES
('".$_POST['id']."',
  '".$_POST['nama']."',
  '".$_POST['asal_sekolah']."',
  '".$_POST['jenis_kelamin']."',
  '".$_POST['nama_ayah']."',
  '".$_POST['nama_ibu']."',
  '".$_POST['alamat']."',
  '".$_POST['no_hp']."',
  '')");
```

Comment: Missing colon information when saving the database. (database columns) should be entered in order of the data colon.